# Find standard form parameters for ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I got this ellipse yesterday with center on x-axis going through points (0, p) and (0, -p) and touching unit circle twice (double contact) at x = t

$$
x^2+y^2-1+\dfrac{1-p^2}{t^2}(x-t)^2=0
$$

Here is the context when I asked for the solution [Perspective view of longitudinal great circles - ellipses inside a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586204/perspective-view-of-longitudinal-great-circles-ellipses-inside-a-circle)

I changed the variable names to $p$ for pole and $t$ for touching point to clarify that this ellipse equation does not contain the semis $a$ and $b$ or the center directly.

Now how to determine center and semi-axis? What I finally did after tons of mistakes is multiply out etc. and put it into general equation, keeping the variables/parameters:

$$
(1 + \dfrac{1-p^2}{t^2}) x^2+y^2 - \dfrac{2(1-p^2)}{t}x - p^2 = 0
$$

I have no $xy$ ("B") or $y$ ("E") in this case, so the long converting equations on wikipedia/ellipse shrink a bit, e.g.

$$
x_0 = \dfrac{2CD}{-4AC}
$$

I this overkill? The semi-axis have a much longer equation.

Because the person who offered the solution guided me to "completing the square". Maybe he was thinking of a specific value pair for $p$ and $t$. But even so this method seems cumbersome, because I don't have nice coefficients, and also I want to find several ellipses with different $p$ and $t$. I must also add/admit that I never heard of this method.

To me it seems these general-form-coefficients to canonical-form-parameters equations on wikipedia are made exactly for a case like this. Now I can go: with given $p$ and $t$ I get such and such A, C, D and F, and thus my $x_0$, $a$ and $b$ are this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ellipse equation is

$$
(1 + \dfrac{1-p^2}{t^2}) x^2+y^2 - \dfrac{2(1-p^2)}{t}x - p^2 = 0
$$

Let $ A = (1 + \dfrac{1-p^2}{t^2}) $ and $ B = - \dfrac{2(1-p^2)}{t} $

Then the equation becomes

$ A x^2 + y^2 + B x = p^2 $

Completing the square in $x$ gives

$ A (x + \dfrac{B}{2A} )^2 - \dfrac{B^2}{4 A} + y^2 = p^2 $

Let $ h = - \dfrac{B}{2A} $ , and $ C = p^2 + \dfrac{B^2}{4A} $

Then the equation now becomes

$ A (x - h)^2 + y^2 = C $

Divide through by $C$

$ \bigg( \dfrac{A}{C} \bigg) (x - h)^2 + \dfrac{1}{C} y^2 = 1 $

So the semi-axes are

$ a =  \sqrt{ \dfrac{C}{A} } $ , and $ b = \sqrt{C} $

And the now the equation is

$ \dfrac{(x - h)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. Your $h$ and my $x_0$ have the same assignments btw.: I could have eliminated $2C$ after leaving out the zero terms. I feel this is the right way to do it, but maybe not for me - I'll use the secret chainsaw.